# Что эффективнее с точки зрения быстродействия: обычный класс с не статическим методом или интерфейс со статическим методом?

Tags: java, java-8, static

Поиск по данному форуму дал понять, что аналогичного вопроса здесь не задавалось.

Имеется класс-валидатор с именем **DataValidator**, в котором используется логирование с помощью **Log4J2**, в котором имеется один метод с именем **isValidString** и он является статическим.

В Java 8 появилась возможность создавать статические методы внутри интерфейса.

Тут возникает вопрос, что логично использовать **с точки зрения быстродействия при компиляции\затрат аппаратных ресурсов**: обычный класс с **не статическим** методом или интерфейс со **статическим** методом. Что выгоднее, постоянно создавать объект класса **DataValidator**, а потом вызывать через имя объекта данного класса метод вот так:

```java
DataValidator dataValidator = new DataValidator();
dataValidator.isValidString("String");
```

или просто использовать статический метод интерфейса без создания объекта класса вот так:

```java
ActionDataValidator.isValidString("String");
```

Вот код класса **DataValidator** с **не статическим** методом:

```java
public class DataValidator {
    static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getRootLogger();
    private static final String VALID_STRING = "^([\\s]*\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(?:\\s*,?\\s*|\\s+))+(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?[\\s]*)$";

    public boolean isValidString(String string) {
        boolean isValid = string.matches(VALID_STRING);

        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "String: \"{}\" is {}.", string, isValid);

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Вот код интерфейса **ActionDataValidator** со **статическим** методом:

```java
public interface ActionDataValidator {
    Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getRootLogger();
    String VALID_STRING = "^([\\s]*\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(?:\\s*,?\\s*|\\s+))+(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?[\\s]*)$";

    static boolean isValidString(String string) {
        boolean isValid = string.matches(VALID_STRING);

        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "String: \"{}\" is {}.", string, isValid);

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Comment: в чем принципиальное отличие этих подходов для вашего кода?

Comment: Почему нельзя сделать ваш DataValidator классом?

Comment: Если метод статический, то как вы его будете использовать у дочерних классах?

Comment: @tym32167, это я и пытаюсь выяснить, какой способ лучше использовать и почему? Почему тот или ной будет эффективнее и правильный с точки зрения проектирования классов?

Comment: @RomanC, отсутствует нужна использовать данный класс в дочерних классах.

Comment: @jlJake Требуется прояснение по вопросу, добавьте больше деталей, объясните что не работает в коде, какая ошибка возникает, что вы пытались сделать. Приведите полный код достаточный, чтобы воспроизвести ошибку. Без деталей и без смысла незачем подавать вопросы на этом сайте. Здесь есть свои правила, и надо их придерживаться. См. как надо задать хороший вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @RomanC, что из заданного непонятно? Вопрос выполнен с соблюдением данных требований https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask